# JS and React Native: Match phone numbers with ones from server

Tags: javascript, string, react-native

I have such situation:

1. Phone number from server with country code always: 380676704338
2. Phone number in phone: 0676704338 or 380676704338

If contacts phone number from phone matches with one from server, it should be replaced with one from server.

What's the best way to implement such logic? There can be situations, when phone number have different length and the body can be the same, like:

```
380 999999999
370 999999999
```

At the moment I check for the last 5 digits of both strings.

```
const isMatch = (str1, str2) => {
    if (str1 === str2) return true;
    if (str2.length < 5) return false;
    return str1.endsWith(str2.slice(-5))
};
```

What's the best way to implement such logic?

Comment: Country is always three digit or it will change in length

Comment: Not always three digit, may be 2

Comment: Or phone number is always 10 digit??

Comment: No, the length can be different, that's why the task is complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `endsWith` only

```js
let server = `380676704338`
let phone = `0676704338`

let match = (server,str) => str.length >= 5 && server.endsWith(str) 

console.log(match(server,phone))
console.log(match(server,'1234567'))
console.log(match(server,'380676704338'))
```